# Labels stuck at top and overlap in form

Tags: html, css, material-design

I'm trying to make a form using [getmdl](https://getmdl.io/). The problem is depicted and is image added:

[image: The labels overlapping]

```
<div id="signup">
            <form action="#" >
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">

                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample1">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1" style="color: indigo;">Username (Required)</label>

                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample2">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2" style="color: indigo;">Email id (Required)</label>
             </div>
           </form>
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
              Add (+)
</button>
</div>
```

In case you are wondering where I got this form code from: [Here](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting each input and label group into their own seperate divs, like so:

```
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="asd" type="text" name="sample1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" id="asd" for="sample1" style="color: indigo;">Username (Required)</label>
     </div>

     <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
         <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample2">
         <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2" style="color: indigo;">Email id (Required)</label>
     </div>
```

is what fixed this for me, it might be because all children of the divs are absolutely positioned, anyway, it should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="signup">
   <form action="#" >
       <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
           <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="asd" type="text" name="sample1">
           <label class="mdl-textfield__label" id="asd" for="sample1" style="color: indigo;">Username (Required)</label>
       </div>
       <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
           <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample2">
           <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2" style="color: indigo;">Email id (Required)</label>
       </div>
   </form>
   <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
              Add (+)
   </button>
</div>
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

of course, if you want the input groups to be stacked and not next to one-another, you should add selectors to the divs that have a higher specificity than the `class` attribute used by `mdl` (unless MDL provides you with a classname to add that provides such funtionality) , so I'd add an id attribute to each div that I want to change, like so:

```
<div id="stacked" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="asd" type="text" name="sample1">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" id="asd" for="sample1" style="color: indigo;">Username (Required)</label>
</div>

<div id="stacked" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">        
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample2">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2" style="color: indigo;">Email id (Required)</label>
</div>
```

Then add this to your CSS:

```
#stacked {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: No problem dude :)